# iOS App Database Choice

Tags: ios, database, web-applications, cloud, storage

Im looking for suggestions on an easy to use cloud based solution for a database. I want to use it for a iOS app and with a web interface, mostly for entering data, probably locally at first but it could spawn into a web app eventually.

I dont need a ton of storage or an expensive solution, just something that I really dont have to manage or do much set up, I want to focus mostly on development, create an interface and set up some tables, add some data and then start development on the iOS app.

Any suggestions/comments?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)?  They are mostly focused on simple cloud based backend that you can setup in minutes.  They have an SDK that you can integrate into your app.

Parse can work across platforms with Android as well.  If you are looking to just implement your app in iOS, you could use a [UIManagedDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIManagedDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class that wraps a CoreData instance of the database locally and can be synced to iCloud.

Comment: Facebook has dropped Parse support.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a simple SQLite file, and sync it through iCloud?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely try using [UIManagedDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIManagedDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIManagedDocument), its the simplest way and you dont have to use any third-party SDK's. You can easily use it to work with SQL files both locally and online (it works really great with iCloud).

Bad is, that there is no sample code or tutorial yet (it's a new iOS 5 function), but you can watch great [presentation](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255) by Paul Hegarty on iTunes U (part 13 - Core Data). Everything important is described there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of CouchDB. http://couchdb.apache.org/

You talk to it using standard http REST style requests, you don't need a client library at all and because all the data is JSON, it's easy to read, understand and work with. Client side you can easily create your own object model to make it pretty trivial to sync objects remotely.

You can host it yourself, or there are cloud solutions available from the likes of Cloudant who I use for a couple of production systems now. They have a free tier to get you started.

https://cloudant.com/